# How to solve this system of conics?

Tags: systems-of-equations, conic-sections

I am currently trying to figure out how to solve the following systems of conics:

$\frac{(x+1)^2}{16} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{81} = 1$

$x+6=\frac{1}{4}(y-1)^2$

How would I find the four points that these two equations intersect?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not plug $4(x+6)$ in place of $(y-1)^2$ in the first equation and solve for $x$? It's quadratic...

Comment: Hint: Write $(y-1)^2=4(x+6)$

Comment: Wow. You are absolutely right. Never even thought about this, went totally above my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short approach would be- 
$\frac{4(x+6)}{81}=\frac{(y-1)^2}{81}$ 
Now substituting in equation one, we get- 
$\frac{(x+1)^2}{16}+\frac{4(x+6)}{81}=1$
It will seem quadratic at first, but for each x value, there are $2$ y-values.
Now simply solve the equation. 
 
[image: Source:wolframalpha.com]

Comment: Yes, this works. I can't tell you how much I appreciate your response, thank you! I will accept this answer when I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer.

Eliminate $(y-1)^2 $ you get two $x$ s.

Plug into the parabola equation and find two $y$ s.